# Is there a way to call a stored procedure using RMySQL?

Tags: mysql, r, stored-procedures

Is there a way to call a stored procedure using RMySQL?  If not, what are alternatives?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is the same way as we query in MySQL.

```
library(DBI)
library(pool)
pool <- dbPool(drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),dbname = "dbname",host = "hostname",username = "username",password = "pwd", port = 3306, unix.sock = "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock")

df <- dbGetQuery(pool, "CALL sampleProcedure();" )
```

`sampleProcedure` is the stored procedure which i have in MySQL.